# notepad++ regex dont know how to add something behind a word

Tags: notepad++

Goodday Guys,
Im going straight to the point.
I have a long list of domains in this form

```
| ipofthehost , subdomain.domain.com |
```

i want to replace the

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

to

```
subdomain.domain.com:80
```

I use this to find each part

```
(\s\,\s\w+\.\w+\.\w+)
```

but when i replace it i have no clue what to write so i add something behind it.
I was wondering if that is possible
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do that:

Find what: `(\s\,\s\w+\.\w+\.\w+)`
Replace with: `$1:80`